# when I try to run an open python file in an integrated terminal, I get an "cant find file" error because the path is passed without delimiters(/)

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code, integrated

When I try to run a .py file in VScode w/Python extension, I get error stating it can't find the file name. name has no delimiters such as /. Folder names and file name are run together e.g."C:Folder1Folder2Filename".

Comment: Can you set the path manually?

Comment: This issue has been fixed. However the first will be available on the next release around the end of the month. In the mean time please use the Insider Build of the extension, see here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#insiders-build